# Can std::exit leak memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, raii

To answer my question, I conducted some tests:

(to replicate following includes are necessary)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
```

I made a function that called `std::exit`, with a `std::unique_ptr` in the `main`function.

```
void some_function()
{
    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> relying_on_raii{new int{5}};
}
```

If I called `some_function` after the `unique_ptr` declaration, memory might leak.

The two logs I got from [Dr. Memory](https://github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory) differed in the following line:

```
1 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
        […]
    6 unique,     6 total,    797 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
```

vs.

```
1 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
        […]
    7 unique,     7 total,    801 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
```

As can be seen, in the second example a 7th potential leak occured, which was 4 bytes in size, which is exactly the size of an `int`. When I repeated this test with double, it indeed turned out to be `805 byte(s)` in the test with `std::exit`.

So is `std::exit` a safe function to use, or should you always return from main to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: If you are calling `exit`, is a leak still a major concern? If you care for the stack to be unwound. Throw an exception that only `main` can catch.

Comment: @StoryTeller I want to use std::exit as the usual way of exiting my program, since I'd have to call return 3 times, with a bool value checking, whether to retrun and it seems easier to do with `std::exit`. `throw` is an interesting idea, but it seems like a hack to throw a successful exit

Comment: If the program is exited what is there to leak?  The OS will clean up the process.

Comment: To be honest, a successful exit not via a return in main is kinda hacky itself.

Comment: @StoryTeller Is it? Is it not even hackier to return from 4 layers of functions?

Comment: See the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit): *Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called.*

Comment: @NathanOliver well, I just want to make sure. Why would dr. memory report additional potential leaks?

Comment: @kim366 - No. It's a natural flow of a program to terminate. It did what it had to do, and now it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is std::exit a safe function to use, or should you always return from main to prevent memory leaks?

Yes, it can leak memory.

That's the less worrisome problem though. The more important problem will be if your program acquired resources that could not be released by shutting down the process. To handle such cases, it is better to either return with some error state until you are able to exit from `main` or use `try-throw-catch` to make sure that `main` is able to catch all uncaught exceptions and exits gracefully.